# SQL Server not displaying message from throw command

Tags: sql-server, throw

I am trying to return custom messages in a SQL Server stored procedure based on errors generated using the throw command. The ERROR condition appears to be generated because it is being passed back to the calling code. However, the custom message is not being displayed.

Here is the snippet of code (@msg and @rowcount are declared earlier in the procedure):

```
set @msg = cast(@rowcount as varchar(5)) + ' records updated';

throw 53000,@msg,1;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `@rowcount` is declared but is it **initialized** with some values ?

Comment: Can you show how `@rowcount` is getting populated?

Comment: That was it. I forgot to initialize the variable. Duh.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure @msg is declared as an nvarchar and allow alternative 0 using *isnull* if @rowcount is null.

```
Declare @msg nvarchar(50)
set @msg = cast(isnull(@rowcount,0) as nvarchar(5)) + N' records updated';
throw 53000, @msg,1;
```